# What are all the references in the "Hey Ferb" song?

Tags: reference, phineas-and-ferb

In the *Phineas and Ferb* episode "Roller Coaster: The Musical", Phineas sings a song named "Hey Ferb":

During the course of the song, different references pop up - I recognize *Fiddler on the Roof* and *Les Mis*, but that's it.

**What are the references in this song?**

Comment: Plenty of Google results, e.g. http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/Hey_Ferb

Comment: @BCdotWEB - feel free to make that an answer :)

Answer (score 7):

[Phineas and Ferb wikia](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/Hey_Ferb) lists them quite well:

> Throughout the accompanying video, Phineas and Ferb parody well-known musicals. This encompasses Cats, The Phantom of the Opera, Oklahoma!, Singin' in the Rain, Fiddler on the Roof, West Side Story, The Music Man, Les Misérables, The King and I, Chicago and finally, Cabaret.

Here are all those references with images:

[Cats (musical)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cats_(musical))

[image]
[image]

[The Phantom of the Opera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Phantom_of_the_Opera_(1986_musical))

[image]
[image]

[Oklahoma!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oklahoma!)

[image]
[image]

[Singin' in the Rain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singin%27_in_the_Rain_(musical))

[image]
[image]

[Fiddler on the Roof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddler_on_the_Roof)

[image]
[image]

[West Side Story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Side_Story)

[image]

[The Music Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Music_Man)

[image]
[image]

[Les Misérables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables_(musical))

[image]
[image]

[The King and I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_King_and_I)

[image]
[image]

[Chicago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_(musical))

[image]
[image]

Also discussed in [this](https://in.pinterest.com/pin/297448750366214164/) pinterest link.

As same wikia link stated, that song also had this line near the end:

> Background singers: Boredom is something up with which I will not put

And Ending a sentence with a preposition "is something up with which I will not put" was famous attribute of [Winston Churchill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winston_Churchill).